# R convert dataframe to term-document-matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, term-document-matrix

I'm currently learning my ways around R and Im troubled by the following problem:

Ive got a dataframe that is build up like this

```
word       freq1        freq2

tree        10           20
this         2            3
that         4            5
...
```

It shows the frequency in which the word is used in text 1 (freq1) and text 2 (freq2). Is it possible to transform this to a term-document-matrix? I need it to be a term-document-matrix to apply the following function

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
comparison.cloud(tdm, random.order=FALSE, colors = 
c("indianred3","lightsteelblue3"),
title.size=2.5, max.words=400)
```

from https://rpubs.com/brandonkopp/creating-word-clouds-in-r

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried the `tm` library or if you already have the terms `wordcloud` and `wordcloud2`?

Comment: Also comparison.cloud takes on a matrix not TDM.

Comment: Hello Hunterofdark, maybe this package/function is helpful: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qdap/versions/2.3.0/topics/as.tdm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** After reshaping your data:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tm)
library(dplyr)
library(wordcloud)
df2<-df %>% 
  gather("Origin","Freq",c(2,3)) %>% 
  acast(word~Origin,fill=0,value.var = "Freq")
comparison.cloud(df2, random.order=FALSE, colors = c("indianred3","lightsteelblue3"),
                 max.words=400)
```

Result:
[image]

**Original answer:**
There is something wrong with your data as it stands. Here is a basic workflow leading up to either a wordcloud or comparison cloud.

```
library(tm)
library(dplyr)
library(wordcloud)
df<-read.table(text="word       freq1        freq2

               Tree        10           20
               This         2            3
               That         4            5",header=T)
df$word<-as.character(df$word)
df1<-df %>% 
  gather()
corpus_my<-Corpus(VectorSource(df1))
tdm<-as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(corpus_my))
comparison.cloud(tdm, random.order=FALSE, colors = c("indianred3","lightsteelblue3"),
                 max.words=400)
```

This gives which is not what you expect. I would suggest restructuring your data first: 
[image]

Comment: This looks helpful! I'll try out when I'm at home. I was aware that probably the structure of my data was a problem but I wasnt sure how to fix it. I'll come back to comment after I tried it out. Many thanks already for your effort :)

Comment: Let me know how it turns out!

Comment: Glad to have helped.